# Installed MySQL but still says command not found

Tags: mysql

I downloaded MySQL's rpm bundle from the site, converted it to a .deb file using alien and installed it by saying `sudo dpkg -i mysql-server_5.6.14-2_amd64.deb`. However, when I say mysql in the command line, it gives an error that it is not installed. What do I do?

I am on Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 64-bit

Comment: Are you trying to install Serve or Client?  Clarify the question.  Because you stated that you're downloading the server edition.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run this command on terminal

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

After install MySQL client you can use 'mysql' command. If you want to install MySQL server you have to run following command.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 4):

If it didn't work,
please try:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-client
```

That worked for me.

Found:
[E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048428/e-package-mysql-client-has-no-installation-candidate-in-php-fpm-image-build-u)

Credits to user Yuan-Chen Ho

Answer (score 1):

Why are you installing an .rpm file?  To install MySQL on Ubuntu, just, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: it's not a rpm package. its a .deb

Comment: @dedunumax The OP states that he downloaded the RPM bundle, and converted to deb.  See question.

Comment: I'm sorry mitch my fault i didnt read whole questiong

Answer (score 1):

The mysql server package doesn't provide a "client"-like binary, but the `mysqld` daemon. If you want to send orders to any mysql server you need to install the client side of mysql which is in another package, the `mysql-client`.

Also, there is no need to manually downloading the deb file. This could lead to broken dependencies. If the package is in the repositories a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide some context of what this command does and why you think it would solve the problem? That way people can decide for themselves if they think it would help.